# No me muestra la Data al HTML

Tags: nodejs, angular, mongodb, binding

No se porque no puedo mostrar la data que recibo desde el html

comentario.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { URL_SERVICIOS } from 'src/config/config';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UsuarioService } from './usuario.service';
import { Comentario } from '../models/comentario.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ComentarioService {

  comentario: Comentario;

  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient,
    public _usuarioService: UsuarioService
  ) { }



  cargarComentarios(id:string){
    let url = URL_SERVICIOS + '/proyecto/comment/' +id;
    url += '?token=' + this._usuarioService.token;
    return this.http.get(url)
          .map((resp:any)=> resp.comentarios)

  }

}
```

comentario.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ComentarioService } from 'src/app/services/comentario.service';
import { Comentario } from 'src/app/models/comentario.model';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comentario',
  templateUrl: './comentario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comentario.component.css']
})
export class ComentarioComponent implements OnInit {

  comentario: Comentario
  title = "Comentarios"

  constructor(
    public _comentarioService: ComentarioService,
    public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {

    activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params=>{
      let id = params['id']
      this.cargarComentarios(id);

    })

    this.comentario = this._comentarioService.comentario;

   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }




  cargarComentarios(id:string){
    this._comentarioService.cargarComentarios(id)
            .subscribe(comentarios=>{
              this.comentario = comentarios
              console.log(comentarios)
            })
  }

}
```

comentario.component.html

```
<div class="card"> 
  <div class="card-body">
    <p>{{comentario.descripcion}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

No me muestra error, hice un `console.log` de la data y parece estar bien

[image: Console.log del HTML Comentario]

proyecto.component.ts

```
<div class="col-12 mt-3">
<app-comentario></app-comentario>
```

Lo llamo desde el selector, que es desde proyecto.component.ts.
Pero esta cuando intento mostrar data, no me da error pero tampoco la muestra

Queda así

[image: HTML del proyecto.component.ts]

Me genera el card pero en blanco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema pasa porque al obtener los datos y querer mostrarlos en pantalla, estas trabajando dicho dato como un **[Objeto](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_objects.htm)** cuando en realidad lo que te retorna es un **[Array](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_arrays.htm)**; aclarado esto sólo debes cambiar esto

```
<div class="card"> 
  <div class="card-body">
    <p>{{comentario.descripcion}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

por esto

```
<div class="card"> 
  <div class="card-body">
    <p>{{comentario[0].descripcion}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Nos comentas si te sirvió :)

Comment: Paulo, eres un genio. Efectivamente ese era el problema.
Ahora unicamente me dice que el valor [0] no esta definido del lado del html

Comment: Como así? Qué error es el que lanza? Podrías incluirlo...

Comment: Luego de modificar y cambiar el valor por {{comentario[0].descripcion}}
Desde el HTLM me dice que ese arreglo de la posicion 0 no esta definido 

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]

Comment: En tu componente declaras **comentario: Comentario**; esto debes cambiarlo ya que como te comenté, estas recibiendo un arreglo, por lo que debería ser un **comentario: Array<Comentario>**

Comment: Excelente Paulo! Agradezco tu tiempo!

Comment: Si te sirvió recuerda aceptar la respuesta para que de esta manera quede cerrada... feliz código colega =)